# How to use imageMagick on Chinese Text to Image Handling

Tags: macos, unicode, imagemagick, utf-8

I try to use ImageMagick to handle a Chinese character to a image on my MacBook.

According to ImageMagick's guide [Unicode or UTF8 Format Text](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/), I tried two ways.

Code one:

```
convert -background lightblue -fill blue \
-size 165X270 -pointsize 24 \
-gravity center -font Andale Mono \
label:'中' label.png
```

Code two:

I write the Chinese character in a text file, and add **.utf8** to its file name.

```
convert -background lightblue -fill blue \
-size 165X270 -pointsize 24 \
-gravity center -font Andale Mono \
label:@chin.utf8 label.png
```

Both do not work. And the result is the same

[image]

Many Thanks In Advance , :-)

Comment: You need to use a TTF file that contains Chinese characters in it - then it will work fine. "Andale Mono" is not the right choice.

Comment: Yes, I will try. i asked a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47775394/how-to-use-imagemagick-with-chinese-fonts-on-text-to-image-handling

Comment: ps: I could not get your `@chin.utf8` command to work.

Comment: I write the Chinese character in a text file, and add .utf8 to its file name.  That is chin.utf8 file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a font that contains Chinese characters, best thing to do is use a Unicode font.

`convert -background lightblue -fill blue \
-size 165X270 -pointsize 24 \
-gravity center -font "/Library/Fonts/Arial Unicode.ttf" \
label:'中' label.png`

You can easily find suitable fonts using macOS Font Book app.

Comment: Can you answer this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47775394/how-to-use-imagemagick-with-chinese-fonts-on-text-to-image-handling

Comment: @dengApro done! :)

Answer (score 0):

An instance answer:

```
convert -background lightblue -fill blue \
-size 165X270 -pointsize 24 \
-gravity center -font "/Library/Fonts/Microsoft/Kaiti.ttf" \ label:'好' labelOne.png
```

Thank **Matt Sephton**'s guide